# Why response.body not readable with xlsx format

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, roo

I want to add the RSpec test for our exporting file with the xlsx file but after getting the index of the end-point with xlsx format, my response.body is not readable and I can't check file contents

rspec:

```rb
it 'returns a successful 200 response for xlsx format' do
  get :index, format: :json

  expect(response).to be_successful
  expect(response.headers['Content-Type']).to eq('my_value'; charset=utf-8')
  expect(response.request.fullpath).to eq('end_poing_path.xlsx')
end
```

but when I want to check `response.body` I got bellow picture

[image: response.body]

Comment: also, I added `render_views` in the parent context

Comment: So your problem is how to write an _expect_ statement for verifying the response?

Comment: no, I want to make a readable response.body

Comment: Define _readable_. The data type of the Response is **String**. If you have an idea what the content of this String is, you can write an `expect` for seeing that this is a _readable_ content, whatever you mean by this.

Comment: xlsx is a zipped directory structure, if you really want to read the file contents, you first have to unzip it, which produces several directories with mostly xml file contents. Then you have to read the xml file that actually has the contents (vs. all the other xlsx 'overhead'), and then extricate the expected contents from xml. It's doable if you are determined, but not trivial.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used `caxlsx` gem and it's can't read Excel files, so I had to install another gem ([Roo](https://github.com/roo-rb/roo) or [simple_xlsx_reader](https://github.com/woahdae/simple_xlsx_reader)) for reading excel files, then I open `response.body` or file with `simple_xlsx_reader` gem

[image]